# How can i get the selected item - Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i have one method to show an list itens, but i need to get the select item and show in a template, how could i do it

method:

```
fieldsForm() {
  return [
    {
      name: "codigoConta",
      data: setOpcaoDefault(getLista().contas),
      label: "Teste",
      type: "list",
      size: 6,
      value: getLista().contas,
      required: true,
    },
```

and i need to put the selected item here:

> Posição do saldo em {{need to put here- the selected item }}{{ new
> Date().toLocaleDateString() }} - {{ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }}

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3BKD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can do this.
I will describe you with an example

Define two variables name `selectedItemIndex` and `selectedItem`

@click on item call a method `itemSelect(index)`

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in list">
  <div @click="itemSelect(index)">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

```js
itemSelect(index) {
  this.selectedItemIndex = index; //selected item index to change background color of  selected item
  this.selectedItem = this.list[index]; //it is your list
}
```

Comment: Instead of `this.selectedItem = this.list[index];` you can have `selectedItem` as a computed data that will return this.list[this.selectedItemIndex] whenever index has a value.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a method to return the selected item (e.g. selectedItem()). You then can insert the selected item by calling the method in the place you want.

```
Posição do saldo em {{ selectedItem() }}{{ new Date().toLocaleDateString() }} - {{ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }}
```